# Can we migrate a Database from Azure Sql Database directly to Azure postgreSql Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure

Is there a way to directly migrate your database in Azure SQL database to the Azure PostgreSQL database (HyperScale-Citus).

I have looked into the Azure migration services but it does not support this particular migration route.

I have an approach in mind but don't know if it will work?

**We can make a backup of the Azure SQL database on the cloud itself 
and then load that backup to Azure PostgreSQL database**

But I do not where to make a backup. In azure blob storage or something else?

Comment: as far as I know, mssql and postgresql are not compatible. You'll need to generate the scripts to create the tables, then insert your data.

Comment: Have you looked at this approach? https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2019/01/23/migrate-from-sql-server-to-postgresql

Comment: Hi Alex-fergi, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist way, you could try the tutorial @ffffff01 provided for you.

There this another way can help you achieve that: [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) can help you migrate the database/data from Azure SQL database to Azure PostgreSQL database directly.

Ref bellow tutorial:

1. [Copy data to and from Azure Database for PostgreSQL by using Azure
   Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-postgresql)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

Create Azure SQL database as source dataset and Azure PostgreSQL database as sink.

Hope this helps.